# sklearn.linear_model.RandomizedLogisticRegression : Handle Categorical Value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I want to use `RandomizedLogisticRegression` for selecting variable for my data set. But the problem is that, One of the feature in my data set is Gender. So it's values are 'F' or 'M' instead of numerical values. As a result I am getting the folllowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 84, in Customer_Acquisition_Binary_Logistics
    self.randomized_Logistic_regression()
  File "main.py", line 92, in randomized_Logistic_regression randomized_logistic.fit(X,y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\randomized_l1.py", line 91, in fit
    X = as_float_array(X, copy=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 112, in as_float_array
    return X.astype(np.float32 if X.dtype == np.int32 else np.float64) ValueError: could not convert string to float: F
```

How can I handle categorical value which are not numeric? Thank you.

Comment: You have to encode them to a numeric value, sklearn understands numeric values, not str values

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the str values into numeric values, for this you could use [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
In [33]:

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
print(le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"]))
​
print(list(le.classes_))
​
print(le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"]) )
​
print(list(le.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1])))
​
LabelEncoder()
['amsterdam', 'paris', 'tokyo']
[2 2 1]
['tokyo', 'tokyo', 'paris']
```